# Cross-browser mobile web solution for full-screen video

Tags: javascript, html, video

A button on my web app triggers an HTML5 video element to play in full screen. This works on iPhones because I added the "webkit-playsinline" element.

However, Androids and many other phones don't support "webkit-playsinline" - and I'm not sure about an alternative solution that is cross-browser mobile compatible.

Any suggestions on how to accomplish this — playing full-screen HTML5 video on Android and other devices?